# how make kmeans on specific columns?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, k-means

I would like to do a K-means on specific columns of my data set. 
As these are categorical data, I plan to do a onehot_encoding on it. Now I would like to know if it is possible to do K-means on specific columns and display the results (of a group for example) with all the columns?

For example i have `col1, col2 and col3`, K-means on `col2 and col3`which are onehot_encoded and display results with `col1, col2 and col3`.
I hope I have clearly expressed my concern

Comment: You could just drop the columns that are not one-hot-encoded for the clustering and then use the labels on the original array/dataframe/.... In any case, it would certainly make it much easier to help you (and the response more specific) if you'd post a snippet of the code you have so far.

Comment: okay thanks, i will write the code post it if i have problems

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This follows the [basic documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html) of kmeans:

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
#here you select your columns
X = df[['col1', 'col2', 'col3']]
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=2, random_state=0).fit(X)
#this will give you the groups back
kmeans.predict(X)
```

So the kmeans predict command will give you the group back which you can add to your original data.